# How to assign a return value from function to a variable

Tags: c, function, cs50

I am trying to assign the return value of `int leftPyramid(void);` to a variable `left` so I can use `printf` to print the pattern.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int leftPyramid(void);

int main(void){
    int left;
```

The following is the code for `int leftPyramid(void);` it creates the following pattern:

```
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

```
int leftPyramid(void);{
    for (int i = 1; i<=num_rows; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=num_rows-i; j++){
            printf(" ");
            }
        for(int k= 1; k<=i; k++){
            printf("#");
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
  
}
```

The following line is causing the error but I can't figure why.

```
left = int leftPyramid(void); //this line seems to be the problem.


int num_rows = get_int("height: \n");
printf("%d", left);
```

Comment: `leftPyramid` doesn't return anything. What value are you wanting `left` to hold after calling `leftPyramid`? "I am trying to assign int leftPyramid(void); to left so i can use printf to print the pattern.": the function is already printing the pattern before returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the prototype of your function:

`int leftPyramid(void);`

in order to call it you need

`left = leftPyramid();`

When you fixed that you will notice the problem mentioned by Carcigenicate in the comment, i.e. you will have to return something meangingful from your function. Sadly I have no idea what that could be, but it is not part of your question.

Comment: Thanks -carcigenicate and -yunnosch i figured out that i had to pass num_rows to leftPyramid. As in void leftPyramid(int num_rows); It works now. thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. I am happy that you also spotted and fixed the weirdness of the controlling variable.